# how to extract numbers from a string ignoring number-letter mixtures

Tags: python, regex

For example, the following regex extracts all "non-numbers" from a string

```
re.sub(r"\b[0-9]+\b", "", "5 1 inch c5 bolts 10")
'  inch c5 bolts '
```

How do I do the opposite?  That is, how do I extract the numbers '5 1 10'?  (Note: c5 is not a number, so it should not be included in the result)

Comment: Is all your input space delimited like "5 1 inch c5 bolts 10"?

Comment: Are the numbers always positive integers? If so, you don't need regex for this.

Comment: Input space varies a great deal, but yes I can assume the numbers are all positive integers

Comment: But there is always *at least* one space between the ints? If so, `[int(x) for x in your_string.split(" ") if x.isdigit()]` to get a list of integers. `[x for x in your_string.split(" ") if x.isdigit()]` to get a list of integers without actually casting them to integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you already know about word boundaries...  You're just looking for a word boundary, a string of numbers (and only numbers) and then another word boundary.  The regex for that is `\b\d+\b`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', "5 1 inch c5 bolts 10")
['5', '1', '10']
```

Comment: Derp.  I've gotten so used to using `replace` I didn't think of `findall`

Comment: Note, my regex is no different than the one above where you are replacing ... Except that I used the shortcut `\d` instead of the slightly more verbose `[0-9]`

Comment: Just as a fun fact, you could use `\b(?!\d+\b)\w+\b` as replace pattern. (Its slower, its less readable.. but it works :P)

Comment: Actually I might need that replace function.. I'm trying to apply this to a Pandas Series of string values.  Since `findall` returns a list, it appears to make the vectorized operation difficult to work whereas `replace` simply returns a string (thus making it easy to vectorize).

Comment: @Ben -- What output do you want exactly?  `'5110'`?  `'5 1 10'`?  Because either of these is trivial to create with the `findall` that I've provided above.

Comment: @Ben If you are calling Python code in each iteration anyway, vectorisation is unlikely to give significant performance improvements.

Comment: The output I want is `'5 1 10'` (which in this example I know I can get with `' '.join(...)` but I'm trying to wrap this inside [pandas.Series.str.findall](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html).  On the other hand, a replacement pattern would make it easy to use [pandas.Series.str.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're only looking for non-negative integers you can do this without regex by using the `str.isdigit` method.

```
s = "5 1 inch c5 bolts 10"
a = [u for u in s.split() if u.isdigit()]
print(a)
b = ' '.join(a)
print(repr(b))
```

**output**

```
['5', '1', '10']
'5 1 10'
```

---

If you actually want a list of the numbers as integers, you can modify the list comprehension like this:

```
a = [int(u) for u in s.split() if u.isdigit()]
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[5, 1, 10]
```